# How to center nonlinear cmap around RdYlGn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I have a list of numbers from -.5 to 0.7. I want the the numbers from -0.5 to 0 to span the full darkest reds in cmap's RdYlGn (at -0.5) to the same cmap 0 that RdYlGn has (yellow) and up to the darkest greens at a cmap of 0.7.

Put another way, I'd like the range of reds of RdYlGn to not range from -4 to 0 but -0.5 to 0. And I'd like the range of greens of RdYlGn to not range from 4 to 0 but 0.7 to 0. DivergingNorm and functions from other stack overflows remaking cdict haven't worked for me thus far.

I'd like to do this without normalizing if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with the original code is hard to say without seeing the code. Also, it's difficult to understand what the numbers `4` and `-4` are doing in the explanation.

Here is an example with a `BoundaryNorm` from `-0.5` to `0.7` and its center at `0`:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
import numpy as np

ymin = -0.5
ymax = 0.7
x = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 1000)
y = np.random.uniform(ymin, ymax, 1000)

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,5))
norm = mcolors.DivergingNorm(vcenter=0, vmin=ymin, vmax=ymax)
scat = ax1.scatter(x, y, s=4, c=y, cmap="RdYlGn", norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(scat, ax=ax1)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

To make the difference even more extreme, an example with limits `-0.2, 0, 0.7`:

[image: second example]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?